# How to set timer, for example 01:24:40:15 (dd HH:mm:ss) format in Angular 11,12,13,14 etc and javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, timer, settimeout, setinterval

**Want to set Time in dd HH:mm:ss format**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

*just mention whatever time you are setting in time variable*

```
startTimer() {
    let time = 86420;
    this.timerFlag = true;
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      --time;
      this.timeLeft = this.transformIntoTimeFormate(time)
      
      if (this.timeLeft == '00:00') {
        this.timerFlag = false;
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        time = 86420;
      }
    }, 1000)
  }

  transformIntoTimeFormate(value: number): string {
    let days: number = Math.floor(value / 86400);
    let hrs: number = Math.floor(value / 3600);
    let minutes: number = Math.floor(value / 60);
    return (
      ('0:0' + days).slice(-2) +':'+('0:0' + hrs).slice(-2) +':'+('0:0' + minutes).slice(-2) +':'+('00'+ Math.floor(value - minutes * 60)).slice(-2)
      );
  }
```

Comment: would be even nicer to use "padStart" instead of slice: `\`${days}\`.padStart(2,'0')`